# Are "anime-physics" questions a good fit for our site?

Tags: discussion, tags

Currently, we have the [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics).

I feel like it's a silly and wouldn't typically warrant a constructive answer. It invites too much speculation and theorycrafting.

So do we really want this to continue? If we do, we should set some guidelines what would make a constructive question.

Answer (score 7):

Questions on anime physics are, in my opinion, fine. For instance, asking how in-universe mechanics work can generate some perfectly valid questions. It's typically impossible to tell *a priori* whether a question like this will be answerable with in-universe information, or if the only possible answers will be speculative. I occasionally see questions like this on [Scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/), which we tend to use as a role-model site, and they can generate good answers. (They can also  generate low-quality speculative answers, but those typically get downvoted and replaced by better answers.)

However, I don't see much use for the tag [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics). I'm not sure who benefits from it. My feeling is that the users who will understand these sorts of things best are the users who are especially familiar with the series; there are no experts in [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) as far as I can tell. I also don't see it being terribly useful for searching or for classification purposes.

Comment: I don't think anime physics remain the same between canons, so I don't think there *can* be an [anime-physics] expert. So I agree: Kill the tag, keep the concept.

Comment: @Eric While there are certain aspects of anime physics which are common among different canons (see e.g. http://www.cs.utah.edu/~duongsaa/more_htm/jk_100animeRules.htm), in my opinion those are already covered by [tag:tropes].