# Is [anime-physics] a tag we should keep?

Tags: discussion, tags

We discussed this before at [Are "anime-physics" questions a good fit for our site?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/are-anime-physics-questions-a-good-fit-for-our-site). There I answered that [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) isn't a very good tag in my opinion. This is a followup to that with the intent to either clarify or delete the tag.

[anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) is, in my opinion, very vague. It seems to deal with almost any in-universe mechanics for any series, as well as certain tropes which exist in multiple universes (see e.g. [this page](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~duongsaa/more_htm/jk_100animeRules.htm)). The [tag wiki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) seems to me to imply it's for this latter category, in which case I think it's entirely covered by [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes), but a lot of the current questions in the tag don't fit that. I don't really know when I'm supposed to apply it. I don't understand why [Why is Steins Gate in the Beta Attractor Field?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6876/why-is-steins-gate-in-the-beta-attractor-field) isn't tagged with it, but [Why do some anime characters never grow old?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/why-do-some-anime-characters-never-grow-old) is.

To me it seems like a meta tag. I can't imagine anyone actually being an expert on anime physics, at least as broadly as it's being defined here. It has all the problems of [character-abilities](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-abilities) which we removed earlier for much the same reason.

Should we remove this tag? If it is going to stay, what objective criteria can be used to make the tag clear, useful, not a meta tag, and not a duplicate of [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes)?

Comment: I still agree that questions of this nature [do not need a tag](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/541/are-anime-physics-questions-a-good-fit-for-our-site#comment1031_542). +1 for removing it.

Comment: First of all, I as an OP of question [Why do some anime characters never grow old?](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/6854/why-do-some-anime-characters-never-grow-old) didn't tag my question with anime physic, but actually I quite like this tag, some question and answer seems good to me but the other has too much speculation and opinion. Maybe we can change it to something better.

Comment: @ShinobuOshino To be clear, we're not talking about removing the ability to ask questions related to anime physics. We're talking about the tag itself, which would not affect any existing questions. (That is, no existing questions have *only* that tag.)

Comment: The consensus seems to be to remove the tag. I'll be removing it from a few questions at a time until it's gone, to avoid flooding the main page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The consensus seemed to be strongly in favor of removing [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics), and I haven't heard any strong opposition to this or attempted clarifications of the tag's purpose and scope. Hence, I've removed it from all questions that had the tag. The tag should be removed from the system within 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

Quite frankly, I have no idea what "anime physics" even is. Unless someone can provide a good definition of what things are and are not covered by the [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) tag, the lack of a solid definition for the topic is reason enough to do away with it.

---

Regarding David Starkey's discussion of being an expert on various things (which I would comment on, but this is a bit long for a comment):

- [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request) - you're right, one cannot be an expert on "identification requests". As long as we allow questions on the topic, though, we kind of have no choice but to allow this tag as an exception.
- [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) - I think one can, in fact, be an expert on "tropes". This expertise comes from wide-ranging experience consuming anime and related media, and understanding what commonalities exist in many different anime, and why they exist. This is, admittedly, a bit difficult to characterize, but I think we can agree that somebody who has watched a lot of anime understands why the protagonist sits in the back row by the window, or what the "anime sweatdrop" means, or whatnot.
- [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) - until I know what this actually means, I have no idea whether or not one can be an expert on it.

Comment: I agree with the point you make on tropes.  As for anime-physics, I could be wrong but I would define it like this: "explanations of how a particular mechanic/system works inside the anime world using real-world science when possible".  Example could be something like "How much energy is in a Kamehameha attack", to which the answer could draw from formulas in real-world physics relating to things like crater sizes and what-not.

Answer (score 0):

I can see reasons for removing as well as for keeping.  <strike>If it were up to me, I see no *harm* in keeping the tag.</strike>  Given Logan's comment, removing is probably the better option.

### Reasons to Keep

- Users that like questions about a certain anime, but do not like questions that would fall under the "anime-physics" realm can easily ignore those ones.
- Users that like thinking about the mechanics behind things could enjoy these questions, regardless of where they come from (and maybe even find some new anime/manga in the process)

### Reasons to Remove

- Many of these questions are within the realm of their respective series, so just the anime/manga name should be sufficient
- Those that go beyond one show fall under the tag [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes)
- When used with a tag of lesser popularity, this tag will take over and be appended to the title

I also want to discuss the claim that having an anime-physics expert is unlikely.  While it is unlikely that any user could be an expert on all  [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics), it is also unlikely for a user to be an expert on all [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes) or [identification-request](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identification-request).  Of the three, I think anime-physics is probably the most likely to master.  After all, the question is asking how a mechanic could work using the known laws of physics while also including any sorts of special cases (i.e. magic)

Comment: The biggest current reason to remove it IMO is one that you've missed. Currently the tag has 14 questions, which makes it around the 30th largest tag. When it is used in conjunction with a smaller series tag, "anime-physics" will be appended to the page title rather than the name of the series, which means the page will not show up in most search results. There's already several examples of this, e.g. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2235/how-is-misakas-railgun-so-destructive. This is a problem with all general tags, so we need to make sure the ones we do have are actually useful.

Comment: I did not know that.  Updated the answer, but I think removal is probably the better option.  Is there a reason why the system would not pick the first tag listed instead?

Comment: Tags are ordered by frequency. I think the method was designed for SO and works there because there are a few big language tags which are the useful ones. It doesn't work as well here because our general tags are bigger than our series tags in some cases. I've [put in a feature request](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/803/low-priority-tags-for-seo) which would alleviate that, but the chances of it happening are low.