# The [technology] tag seems a bad idea

Tags: discussion, tags

Tag [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) is only used on 4 questions. In the few questions it is used, [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) is a better fit.

We're already having [a similar discussion](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/808/is-anime-physics-a-tag-we-should-keep) about [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics).

Comment: Now there's only 1 question tagged and it's off-topic about visual novel game development reverse-engineering :\

Answer (score 4):

Here are the four questions that currently bear the [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) tag:

- [How does Gilgamesh have a futuristic fighter plane?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/313/gilgameshs-ancient-fighter-plane) - on this question, the use of [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) is very much like the now-proscribed use of [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics). As such, I have taken the liberty of removing it.
- [How do you extract texts into a text format that you can copy and paste from visual novels?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/28/how-do-you-extract-texts-into-a-text-format-that-you-can-copy-and-paste-from-vis) - this question is about technology that specifically affects the anime-consuming experience (or, in this case, the VN experience). There are no other tags that could go on this question as it currently stands. The only tag that might fit is "visual-novel", but that tag does not and should not exist, so I'm not really sure what to do about this.
- [What did the [C]: Control production use for their cel-shading?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/5355/what-did-the-c-control-production-use-for-their-cel-shading) - as you point out, this use of [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) is subsumed by [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production).
- https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/animes-and-mangas-about-cold-war - this was a bad question (a recommendation request), has been closed, and will eventually be deleted, so there's nothing to worry about there.

---

The two valid questions with [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) (the second and third) fall into two categories - technology used by the anime consumer, and technology used by the anime producer.

For the latter, I think it is clear that we should just go ahead and tag it with [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production). I don't see any benefit to having tags for things that are strict subsets of "anime production", because I find it vanishingly unlikely that we will ever have people here who are experts on anime production technology but not the rest of anime prodution.

For questions about technology used by the anime consumer, though, I can see some merit to the tag, if such questions are considered on-topic. Judging from the closure of the question, though, I guess the verdict was that these questions were not, in fact, on topic.<sup>1</sup> This being the case, we basically have two options: either go around actively killing [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) every time someone uses it (and sticking a big "DO NOT USE THIS TAG" notice in the wiki), or finding a better tag for this question (but as I noted above, there probably isn't a better tag).

<sup>1</sup> I do not agree with this and will probably make a meta post on the topic at some point.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the VN question was during the private beta period, and was fairly contentious then (see http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/11/are-questions-about-technical-aspects-of-visual-novels-on-topic). It's probably worth considering again what to do with these sorts of questions.